# Can we use NSOutlineView source list in 10.5

Tags: macos, cocoa

In a cocoa application supporting 10.5 onward I want to create a pane in my windows that looks like iTunes/Finder pane on the left side.

After doing a bit of research I think NSOutlineView should support it, however it looks like source list view of NSOutlineView only supports 10.6 onwards and is not supported in 10.5, is this correct or is there a way to use NSOutlineView source list so that works with 10.5 as well.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

[this blog](http://chanson.livejournal.com/176310.html) indicates that source lists appeared in 10.5 so it should work on 10.5+. there are  tutorials out there for implementing an `NSTableView` subclass to mimic them on earlier OS versions.